# Using a framework in a PreferencePane

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, plugins, linker

i am currently trying to implement a "third party framework" (FeedbackReporter.Framework) into my preferencepane.

Unfortunately I am getting the following error all the time when trying to launch my preference pane:

> 16.05.10 23:13:30 System Preferences[32645] dlopen_preflight
>   failed with
>   dlopen_preflight(/Users/me/Library/PreferencePanes/myPane.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/myPane):
>   Library not loaded:
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/FeedbackReporter.framework/Versions/A/FeedbackReporter
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/me/Library/PreferencePanes/myPane.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/myPane
>   Reason: image not found for
>   /Users/me/Library/PreferencePanes/myPane.prefPane

As far as I read so far, this problem is probably caused because my prefPane is no actual app, but a "plugin" of "System Settings.app" and thus @executable_path resolves to a path within the bundle of this app, instead of the bundle of my prefpane.

But I don't really picked up howto fix this problem. I guess it must be fairly easy since it should be a usual case that people use non-apple-frameworks in PreferencePanes.

Thanks for your hints!

--
Short Update:
As far as I understood tons of docs I read so far, there might be a setting which has to be done in the third-party framework. Obviously the "install path" has to be set to "loader_path" instead to "executable_path" in order to work in a preferencepane.

But since I am using a precompiled framework (FeedbackReporter.framework) this is probably a setting which the author has to change?! and even if i could compile the framework myself, i had no idea where to change this install_path in Xcode.

Comment: Obviously this is in fact something that the framework developer has to change. i noticed a similar change in the growl framework (they uses @executable_path before and now use @loader_path.

For people with the same problem with the FeedbackReporter.framework:
http://getsatisfaction.com/vaferorg/topics/use_loader_path_instead_of_executable_path

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot wait for the next release just download the source, change it in

```
FeedbackReporter.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

and then open and compile the framework yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can change it yourself without recompiling the third party framework.  You can use `install_name_tool` to change where a MachO binary will look for shared object libraries.  First use `otool -L <binary file for your plugin>` to get the paths of where it expects its libraries to be, then use `install_name_tool -change ...` to change the paths in that file.  Repeat for any bundled frameworks.